# How to send multiple sequentially timed https requests with NodeJS?

Tags: json, node.js, https, delay

I want to send multiple https requests using NodeJS. **Each must be fired within a chosen delay in seconds.** I used this code:

```
const https = require('https');
const sleep = require('sleep');

function sendData(time) {

  var postData = JSON.stringify({
    "time":time
  });

  var options = {
    host: 'hostname.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Content-Length': postData.length
       }
  };

  var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var timeDate = new Date();
   sendData(timeDate.getTime());
   console.log("Sleeping for some seconds...");
   sleep.sleep(10);
}
```

The output is as follows:

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**Sleeping for some seconds...**

**< < < ALL SERVER RESPONSES AT ONCE > > >**

As shown, all responses arrived at once, as if the program waited for all for iterations to complete before sending the https requests all at once, and not once every 10 seconds, as intended...

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to schedule when things run, NOT `sleep()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()`, not `sleep()` to schedule an activity for some future time:

```
const delay = 3000;     // set to whatever you want the spacing to be in ms
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("sending data " + i);
       var timeDate = new Date();
       sendData(timeDate.getTime());
   }, delay * i);
}
```

You do not want to use the sleep module for pretty much anything except debugging because it blocks the entire node.js event loop which does not allow anything else to run, including your network requests.  Instead, you need to program node.js using asynchronous logic (like with `setTimeout()`) that works properly with the event loop design of node.js.

---

Note: This is what you asked for, sending multiple requests spaced out in time.  But, when I look at what you're doing with the results, it appears you want to make sure that all results arrive and are processed in order.  Sending requests spaced out in time does not necessarily guarantee that.  It makes it likely, but not certain.  If you wanted to guarantee arrival order or guarantee processing order, you would need additional code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval(callback, delay)
https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args

The first parameter `callback` accepts a function to be executed.
The second parameter `delay` accepts time in milliseconds.
The callback will execute every time the delay elapses.

```
let sendDataEveryTenSeconds = setInterval(function(){
    sendData(Date());
},1000);
```

So every 1000ms (10 seconds), the anonymous function that calls `sendData(Date())` will execute.

In your example, you want it to stop after 3 times. `setInterval` returns a reference to the timed execution, which you can store in a variable and later call `clearInterval` to stop execution when needed. In your case, you could setup a counter that tracks when the function has executed 3 times.

```
clearInterval(sendDataEveryTenSeconds);
```

Comment: Thanks, Daryl T. This also worked, but I ended up using the setTimeout function within a for loop, as suggested by jfriend00. :)